# Break a number down int array and get factorial of each number - C programming

Tags: c, sum, factorial, digit

I apologize in advance for the length of the code and how tedious it may be to follow. I am trying to break a number down into individual digits and get the factorial of each one. I have successfully done that (with the help of paxdiablo) but I want to do this all the way from 99999 to 0. In order to do that I have placed all of the code in a loop starting indx at 99999 and decreasing value until it reaches 1. The reason I am trying to do this is because I need to compare the sum of the factorial of each individual digit to the number and if they are equal then I have a match. The program runs and the first run for the number 99999 works perfectly fine but the next loop SHOULD be 99998 and do the exact same thing but instead the next number is 4. I have no idea why it would do this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int num;
    int indx;
    int fact = 1;
    int individualDigit[50];
    int length;

    for(indx = 99999; indx > 0; indx--)
    {
        num = indx;
        for (length = 0; num > 0; length++, num /= 10)
        {
            individualDigit[length] = num % 10;
        }
        printf ("Digit count = %d, digits =", length);

        for (indx = length - 1; indx >= 0; indx--)
        {
            printf (" %d", individualDigit[indx]);
        }

        for (indx = 0; indx < length; indx++)
        {
            while (individualDigit[indx] > 0)
            {
                fact = fact * individualDigit[indx];
                individualDigit[indx]--;
            }
            printf("\n%d ", fact);
            fact = 1;
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The value in "indx" is being used by multiple for loops. The line

```
for (indx = 0; indx < length; indx++)
```

increments indx back up to 4, which is the value used by your outer loop. Just use some new variables to count the different loops

Comment: Thanks! Something so simple!    If you could help as well, how would I add up each individual factorial?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a homework question and your code quality seems to confirm that so I'm hesitant to write you actual code but I'll give you a few pointers.

1. As @Cody Braun said above your index variable is getting overwritten in line 23 where you calculate the factorial.
2. There is a much more efficient way to calculate factorials using [dynamic programming](https://gyaneshwarpardhi.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/factorial-program-using-dynamic-programming/)
3. I don't know if you just didn't want to do it in the post but learning [how to properly format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638561/what-is-the-proper-way-to-format-code) will help you catch these errors quicker and keep yourself form making them. As well as make it easier for others to read your code.

Cheers