# Problem in shell code to find happy prime number

Tags: shell

This is my code to find happy prime number, I don't know why it is giving error.
#!/bin/bash
happy(){
rem = $0
sum = $0
while [ $result -gt 0 ];
do
rem = $((result%10))
p = $((rem*rem))
sum = $((sum + p))
result = $((result/10))
done
return $sum
}
echo "Enter a number"
read num
for (( i=1; i<101; i++ ))
do
result=$i
while [ $result -ne 0 && $result -ne 4 ];
do
happy $result
done
if [ $?==1 ]
then echo "happy number"
else
echo "not a happy number"
fi
done

Comment: Please look at your own post: Your program is barely readable in that way. You are expected to [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638561/what-is-the-proper-way-to-format-code) properly.

Answer (score 0):

I see lots of syntax errors and some logical errors in your script.
This should be a fixed version (works at least for 13 and 4 :))

Errors I've found:

- `rem = $0` and similar: the spaces around assignments are not allowed in bash,
- `rem = $0`: you assign a value that is never used,
- `rem = $0` and `sum = $0` the first argument passed to the function is `$1` not `$0`,
- the input number is assigned to `num` but never used,
- the exit condition from the for and while loops is broken,
- ...

```
#!/bin/bash

happy()
{
    result=$1
    sum=0
    while [ $result -gt 0 ]; do
        rem=$(( result % 10 ))
        p=$(( rem * rem ))
        sum=$(( sum + $p ))
        result=$(( result / 10 ))
    done
    echo "$sum"
}

echo "Enter a number"
read num
result=$num

for (( i=1; i<101; i++ )) do
    result=$(happy $result)
    if [ $result == 1 ]; then
       echo "$num is a happy number"
       exit
    fi
done

echo "$num is not a happy number"
```

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, consider marking it as "accepted" by clicking on the check mark icon @Nur